# Is there any way to hide the variables that are being passed to Flash by swfobject when someone views source?

Tags: flash, security, swfobject, externalinterface, view-source

I have some Flash swfs that are embedded using swfobject and I pass them some vars like user id. How do I prevent people from reading these vars? If someone views the source of the php page that embeds the swfs they can see all the variables that are being passed to flash. Is there a way to hide these vars? What other ways are there to do this? I have thought about setting up an ExternalInterface and calling a javascript function to pass the vars to Flash - would this effectively hide the data I am sending?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot actually hide the data. you can only make it harder to find. using firebug or similar tools, people will always find out, since they can look at what your JS does, and at the data your app sends. the best you can do is to add some encryption, but using a decompiler, one can easily extract the decryption mechanism from the swf.

if you described the general problem (what kind of data is being sent and why/against what you want it protected), maybe I could provide more specific ideas.

**edit:** this seems like a serious security flaw to me. a restricted service should only grant access to properly authenticated users. the flash client should never pass its user id. instead, a session (as created by a login) should be associated with a user, thus permitting identification. so your client will never even know of its user ID. it will just send a request and the PHP session will permit to find out this user ID and provide the corresponding data.

Comment: thanks, most of the data is to do with the user, it is a user id and a group id to allow Flash to call a page (AMFPHP) that queries the database for images belonging to that user and then loads images from a remote server. I also pass an IP address of the location of these images (this IP address is for amazon web services and may change so I dont want to hard code). I am most worried that someone could manually (somehow) enter a different user id and be able to see other user's material. Can Flash get access to PHP session vars to check if the passed user id = session user id?

Comment: Hi Back2Dos,

Thanks for your responses, one problem I have with using a PHP session to store the user id is that the Flash client sometimes calls 2 servers, so I will need to use something like session clustering (quick google of problem), mCaching etc. Our webserver is located at one host and our other server that will need to know the user id is located on Amazon Web Services. It sounds like perhaps the easiest thing to do is to create a 'session' record in the database when a user logs in and have both servers read the user id from this record. Can you suggest any alternative solutions?